# Issues upgrading from wagtail 2.15.6 to 2.16 breaks all pages except home page

Tags: upgrade, wagtail

I am experiencing an issue upgrading a site's wagtail installed version. I have successfully upgraded from 2.12 to 2.15.6 but am running into what seems to be an impassible issue with upgrading to 2.16 Specifically to do with this recent commit in 2.16 stable

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/commit/29a7f701611d22ab9c7f12f1134aeac1d31b9438

Every page except the root page of the site brings up the following error (including django and wagtail admins)

```
AttributeError at /django-admin/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'root_path'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/django-admin/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'tuple' object has no attribute 'root_path'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py, line 1109, in <genexpr>
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.14
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 09 Dec 2022 15:42:48 -0500

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/django-admin/

Django Version: 3.2
Python Version: 3.7.14

Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'globalapp.middleware.request.RequestMiddleware',
 'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'righttoplay.middleware.CustomCacheMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 168, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 244, in bind_template
    updates.update(processor(self.request))
  File "/app/globalapp/context_processors.py", line 8, in site_settings
    return {"settings" : national_office.serialized_data }
  File "/app/globalapp/models.py", line 1542, in serialized_data
    if self.privacy_page
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py", line 1214, in get_url
    url_parts = self.get_url_parts(request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py", line 1130, in get_url_parts
    possible_sites = self._get_relevant_site_root_paths(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py", line 1108, in _get_relevant_site_root_paths
    for srp in self._get_site_root_paths(cache_object)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py", line 1109, in <genexpr>
    if self.url_path.startswith(srp.root_path)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /django-admin/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'root_path'
```

None of this was documented as a breaking change in the upgrade process I've been following here

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/2.16.html

Technical details
-Python Version is 3.7 running in a docker container

Im including the requirements.txt here if there are any further package or dependancy changes I need to make that arent outlined please let me know.

```
aiosignal==1.2.0
anyascii==0.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==22.1.0
azure-core==1.25.1
azure-storage-blob==12.13.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2022.9.24
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
cryptography==38.0.1
Deprecated==1.2.13
Django==3.2
django-ajax-selects==2.2.0
django-cogwheels==0.3
django-email-extras==0.3.4
django-extensions==3.1.5
django-filter==2.4.0
django-modelcluster==5.3
django-modeltranslation==0.18.2
django-redis==5.2.0
django-storages==1.12.3
django-taggit==2.0
django-treebeard==4.5.1
django-user-agents==0.4.0
djangorestframework==3.13.1
docopt==0.4.0
draftjs-exporter==2.1.7
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
frozenlist==1.3.1
future==0.18.2
geoip2==4.6.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
html5lib==1.1
idna==3.4
isodate==0.6.1
l18n==2021.3
mailchimp3==3.0.17
mandrill==1.0.60
maxminddb==2.2.0
msrest==0.7.1
multidict==6.0.2
oauthlib==3.2.1
openpyxl==3.0.10
packaging==21.3
Pillow==8.4.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
pycparser==2.21
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-gnupg==0.5.0
pytz==2022.2.1
redis==4.3.4
requests==2.28.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
sqlparse==0.4.3
tablib==3.2.1
telepath==0.3
typing_extensions==4.3.0
ua-parser==0.16.1
Unidecode==1.3.6
urllib3==1.26.12
user-agents==2.2.0
wagtail==2.16
wagtail-condensedinlinepanel==0.5.3
wagtail-clear-cache==0.0.1
wagtail-modeltranslation==0.10.18
wagtailgmaps==1.0.1
wagtailmedia==0.9.0
wagtailmenus==3.1.2
webencodings==0.5.1
whitenoise==6.2.0
Willow==1.4.1
wrapt==1.14.1
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter==1.4.5
xlwt==1.3.0
yarl==1.8.1
```

Following the upgrade docs https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/2.16.html ran into this unexpected / undocumented issue.

Here is the context_processor that is causing the issue. which is getting a model of National Office which has on it multiple Pages that are foreign keys of wagtailcore.Page and the serialized_data method has some if statements checking for if the page foreign key exists and it is these checks that are triggering the wagtailcore code that is failing.

```
def site_settings(request):
    domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST'].replace("www.", "")
    try:
        national_office = NationalOffice.objects.get(domain=domain)
        return {"settings" : national_office.serialized_data }
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print(" NO Not Found ")
        return {}
```

The below is the serialized data method and it is erroring on the if self.privacy_page check which is the first occurrence of the model's foreign keys to the wagtailcore.Page in this serialized_data method

```
@property
    def serialized_data(self):
        global_settings = GlobalSiteSettings.objects.all()[0]
        languages = []
        for language in self.languages.all():
            languages.append(language.serialized_data)

        static_text = None
        global_settings = GlobalSiteSettings.objects.all()[:1].get()

        if global_settings:
            static_text = global_settings.static_text

        national_offices = []
        for national_office in NationalOffice.objects.all():
            national_offices.append(
                {
                    "name": national_office.name,
                    "domain": national_office.domain,
                    "default_language_short_name": national_office.default_language.short_name
                    if national_office.default_language
                    else "en",
                    "current": True if national_office.id == self.id else False,
                    "flag": self.flag,
                    "append_to_url": "?no-redirect=true"
                    if national_office.redirect_by_geo_ip
                    else None,
                }
            )

        data = {
            # static
            "static_text": static_text,
            "national_offices": national_offices,
            "name": self.name,
            "flag": self.flag,
            "domain": self.domain,
            "gmt_code": self.gmt_code,
            # language
            "show_language_switcher": True if len(languages) > 1 else False,
            "languages": languages,
            "default_language_short_name": self.default_language.short_name,
            # header
            "announcement_text": self.announcement_text,
            "announcement_link": self.announcement_link,
            "join_nav_txt_1": self.join_nav_txt_1,
            "join_nav_url_1": self.join_nav_url_1,
            "join_nav_txt_2": self.join_nav_txt_2,
            "join_nav_url_2": self.join_nav_url_2,
            "join_nav_txt_3": self.join_nav_txt_3,
            "join_nav_url_3": self.join_nav_url_3,
            "footer_col_1_text_1": self.footer_col_1_text_1,
            "footer_col_1_url_1": self.footer_col_1_url_1,
            "footer_col_1_text_2": self.footer_col_1_text_2,
            "footer_col_1_url_2": self.footer_col_1_url_2,
            "footer_col_1_text_3": self.footer_col_1_text_3,
            "footer_col_1_url_3": self.footer_col_1_url_3,
            "footer_col_2_text_1": self.footer_col_2_text_1,
            "footer_col_2_url_1": self.footer_col_2_url_1,
            "footer_col_2_text_2": self.footer_col_2_text_2,
            "footer_col_2_url_2": self.footer_col_2_url_2,
            "footer_col_2_text_3": self.footer_col_2_text_3,
            "footer_col_2_url_3": self.footer_col_2_url_3,
            "footer_col_3_text_1": self.footer_col_3_text_1,
            "footer_col_3_url_1": self.footer_col_3_url_1,
            "footer_col_3_text_2": self.footer_col_3_text_2,
            "footer_col_3_url_2": self.footer_col_3_url_2,
            "footer_col_3_text_3": self.footer_col_3_text_3,
            "footer_col_3_url_3": self.footer_col_3_url_3,
            "primary_donation_url": self.primary_donation_url
            if self.primary_donation_url
            else None,
            "primary_donation_page": self.primary_donation_page
            if self.primary_donation_page
            else None,
            "show_fundraise_link": self.show_fundraise_link,
            "show_events_link": self.show_events_link,
            "show_get_involved_link": self.show_get_involved_link,
            "show_third_party_events": self.show_third_party_events,
            # footer
            "facebook_url": self.facebook_url
            if self.facebook_url
            else global_settings.facebook_url,
            "twitter_url": self.twitter_url
            if self.twitter_url
            else global_settings.twitter_url,
            "instagram_url": self.instagram_url
            if self.instagram_url
            else global_settings.instagram_url,
            "linkedin_url": self.linkedin_url
            if self.linkedin_url
            else global_settings.linkedin_url,
            "youtube_url": self.youtube_url
            if self.youtube_url
            else global_settings.youtube_url,
            "business_number_title": self.business_number_title
            if self.business_number_title
            else None,
            "business_number_value": self.business_number_value
            if self.business_number_value
            else None,
            "business_logo1": self.logo1 if self.logo1 else None,
            "business_logo2": self.logo2 if self.logo2 else None,
            "business_logo1_url": self.logo1_url if self.logo1_url else None,
            "business_logo2_url": self.logo2_url if self.logo2_url else None,
            "contact_director_name": self.contact_director_name
            if self.contact_director_name
            else None,
            "contact_director_title": self.contact_director_title
            if self.contact_director_title
            else None,
            "contact_address": self.contact_address if self.contact_address else None,
            "contact_phone": self.contact_phone if self.contact_phone else None,
            "contact_email": self.contact_email if self.contact_email else None,
            "contact_show_program_offices": self.contact_show_program_offices
            if self.contact_show_program_offices
            else False,
            "footer_subscribe_title": self.footer_subscribe_title
            if self.footer_subscribe_title
            else global_settings.footer_subscribe_title,
            "shop_page_url": self.shop_page if self.shop_page else None,
            "shop_page_title": self.shop_page_title if self.shop_page_title else None,
            "privacy_page_url": self.privacy_page.url
            if self.privacy_page
            else global_settings.privacy_page.url
            if global_settings.privacy_page
            else None,
            "privacy_page_title": self.privacy_page.title
            if self.privacy_page
            else global_settings.privacy_page.title
            if global_settings.privacy_page
            else None,
            "terms_page_url": self.terms_page.url
            if self.terms_page
            else global_settings.terms_page.url
            if global_settings.terms_page
            else None,
            "terms_page_title": self.terms_page.title
            if self.terms_page
            else global_settings.terms_page.title
            if global_settings.terms_page
            else None,
            "faq_page_url": self.faq_page.url
            if self.faq_page
            else global_settings.faq_page.url
            if global_settings.faq_page
            else None,
            "faq_page_title": self.faq_page.title
            if self.faq_page
            else global_settings.faq_page.title
            if global_settings.faq_page
            else None,
            "contact_page_url": self.contact_page.url
            if self.contact_page
            else global_settings.contact_page.url
            if global_settings.contact_page
            else None,
            "contact_page_title": self.contact_page.title
            if self.contact_page
            else global_settings.contact_page.title
            if global_settings.contact_page
            else None,
            "search_page_url": global_settings.search_page.url
            if global_settings.search_page
            else None,
            "resources_page_url": self.resources_page.url
            if self.resources_page
            else None,
            "resources_page_title": self.resources_page.title
            if self.resources_page
            else None,
            "more_ways_to_give_page_url": self.more_ways_to_give_page.url
            if self.more_ways_to_give_page
            else None,
            "more_ways_to_give_page_title": self.more_ways_to_give_page.title
            if self.more_ways_to_give_page
            else None,
            "more_ways_to_give_page": self.more_ways_to_give_page
            if self.more_ways_to_give_page
            else None,
            "careers_page": self.careers_page if self.careers_page else None,
            "media_center_page": self.media_center_page
            if self.media_center_page
            else None,
            "campaign_page": self.campaign_page if self.campaign_page else None,
            "we_rise_page": self.we_rise_page if self.we_rise_page else None,
            "footer_accessibility_url": self.footer_accessibility_url
            if self.footer_accessibility_url
            else None,
            "footer_accessibility_title": self.footer_accessibility_title
            if self.footer_accessibility_title
            else None,
            "fundraise_page_url": self.fundraise_page.url
            if self.fundraise_page
            else None,
            "fundraise_page_title": self.fundraise_page.title
            if self.fundraise_page
            else None,
            # generic bottom cta
            "generic_bottom_cta_title": self.generic_bottom_cta_title
            if self.generic_bottom_cta_title
            else None,
            "generic_bottom_cta_body": self.generic_bottom_cta_body
            if self.generic_bottom_cta_body
            else None,
            "generic_bottom_cta_button_text": self.generic_bottom_cta_button_text
            if self.generic_bottom_cta_button_text
            else None,
            "generic_bottom_cta_button_page": self.generic_bottom_cta_button_page
            if self.generic_bottom_cta_button_page
            else None,
            "generic_bottom_cta_button_url": self.generic_bottom_cta_button_url
            if self.generic_bottom_cta_button_url
            else None,
            "cookie_text": self.cookie_text
            if self.cookie_text
            else global_settings.cookie_text,
            "cookie_agree_text": self.cookie_agree_text
            if self.cookie_agree_text
            else global_settings.cookie_agree_text,
            # homepage overrides
            "top_carousel_type": self.top_carousel_type
            if self.top_carousel_type is not "default"
            else None,
            "top_carousel_image": self.top_carousel_image
            if self.top_carousel_image
            else None,
            "top_carousel_title": self.top_carousel_title
            if self.top_carousel_title
            else None,
            "top_carousel_button_page": self.top_carousel_button_page
            if self.top_carousel_button_page
            else None,
            "top_carousel_button_text": self.top_carousel_button_text
            if self.top_carousel_button_text
            else None,
            "home_hide_top_carousel_text": self.home_hide_top_carousel_text,
            "home_hide_top_carousel_button": self.home_hide_top_carousel_button,
            "home_section_0_visible": self.home_section_0_visible,
            "home_section_0_title": self.home_section_0_title
            if self.home_section_0_title
            else None,
            "home_section_0_body": self.home_section_0_body
            if self.home_section_0_body
            else None,
            "home_section_0_body_mobile": self.home_section_0_body_mobile
            if self.home_section_0_body_mobile
            else None,
            "home_section_0_button_text": self.home_section_0_button_text
            if self.home_section_0_button_text
            else None,
            "home_section_0_button_url": self.home_section_0_button_url
            if self.home_section_0_button_url
            else None,
            "home_section_0_light_foreground": self.home_section_0_light_foreground
            if self.home_section_0_light_foreground != "none"
            else None,
            "home_section_0_text_align": self.home_section_0_text_align
            if self.home_section_0_text_align != "none"
            else None,
            "home_section_0_background_image": self.home_section_0_background_image
            if self.home_section_0_background_image
            else None,
            "home_section_0_button_url": self.home_section_0_button_url
            if self.home_section_0_button_url
            else None,
            "home_section_0_button_page": self.home_section_0_button_page
            if self.home_section_0_button_page
            else None,
            "home_section_1_title": self.home_section_1_title
            if self.home_section_1_title
            else None,
            "home_section_1_body": self.home_section_1_body
            if self.home_section_1_body
            else None,
            "home_section_1_body_mobile": self.home_section_1_body_mobile
            if self.home_section_1_body_mobile
            else None,
            "home_section_1_button_text": self.home_section_1_button_text
            if self.home_section_1_button_text
            else None,
            "home_section_1_button_url": self.home_section_1_button_url
            if self.home_section_1_button_url
            else None,
            "home_section_1_light_foreground": self.home_section_1_light_foreground
            if self.home_section_1_light_foreground != "none"
            else None,
            "home_section_1_text_align": self.home_section_1_text_align
            if self.home_section_1_text_align != "none"
            else None,
            "home_section_1_background_image": self.home_section_1_background_image
            if self.home_section_1_background_image
            else None,
            "home_section_1_button_url": self.home_section_1_button_url
            if self.home_section_1_button_url
            else None,
            "home_section_1_button_page": self.home_section_1_button_page
            if self.home_section_1_button_page
            else None,
            "home_section_2_title": self.home_section_2_title
            if self.home_section_2_title
            else None,
            "home_section_2_body": self.home_section_2_body
            if self.home_section_2_body
            else None,
            "home_section_2_body_mobile": self.home_section_2_body_mobile
            if self.home_section_2_body_mobile
            else None,
            "home_section_2_button_text": self.home_section_2_button_text
            if self.home_section_2_button_text
            else None,
            "home_section_2_button_url": self.home_section_2_button_url
            if self.home_section_2_button_url
            else None,
            "home_section_2_light_foreground": self.home_section_2_light_foreground
            if self.home_section_2_light_foreground != "none"
            else None,
            "home_section_2_text_align": self.home_section_2_text_align
            if self.home_section_2_text_align != "none"
            else None,
            "home_section_2_background_image": self.home_section_2_background_image
            if self.home_section_2_background_image
            else None,
            "home_section_2_button_url": self.home_section_2_button_url
            if self.home_section_2_button_url
            else None,
            "home_section_2_button_page": self.home_section_2_button_page
            if self.home_section_2_button_page
            else None,
            "home_section_3_title": self.home_section_3_title
            if self.home_section_3_title
            else None,
            "home_section_3_body": self.home_section_3_body
            if self.home_section_3_body
            else None,
            "home_section_3_body_mobile": self.home_section_3_body_mobile
            if self.home_section_3_body_mobile
            else None,
            "home_section_3_button_text": self.home_section_3_button_text
            if self.home_section_3_button_text
            else None,
            "home_section_3_button_url": self.home_section_3_button_url
            if self.home_section_3_button_url
            else None,
            "home_section_3_light_foreground": self.home_section_3_light_foreground
            if self.home_section_3_light_foreground != "none"
            else None,
            "home_section_3_text_align": self.home_section_3_text_align
            if self.home_section_3_text_align != "none"
            else None,
            "home_section_3_background_image": self.home_section_3_background_image
            if self.home_section_3_background_image
            else None,
            "home_section_3_button_url": self.home_section_3_button_url
            if self.home_section_3_button_url
            else None,
            "home_section_3_button_page": self.home_section_3_button_page
            if self.home_section_3_button_page
            else None,
            "home_section_4_title": self.home_section_4_title
            if self.home_section_4_title
            else None,
            "home_section_4_body": self.home_section_4_body
            if self.home_section_4_body
            else None,
            "home_section_4_article": self.home_section_4_article
            if self.home_section_4_article
            else None,
            "home_section_4_button_text": self.home_section_4_button_text
            if self.home_section_4_button_text
            else None,
            "home_section_4_light_foreground": self.home_section_4_light_foreground
            if self.home_section_4_light_foreground
            else None,
            "home_section_4_text_align": self.home_section_4_text_align
            if self.home_section_4_text_align
            else None,
            "home_section_4_image_override": self.home_section_4_image_override
            if self.home_section_4_image_override
            else None,
            "home_featured_article_1": self.home_featured_article_1
            if self.home_featured_article_1
            else None,
            "home_featured_article_2": self.home_featured_article_2
            if self.home_featured_article_2
            else None,
            "home_featured_article_3": self.home_featured_article_3
            if self.home_featured_article_3
            else None,
            "home_bottom_cta_title": self.home_bottom_cta_title
            if self.home_bottom_cta_title
            else None,
            "home_bottom_cta_button_text": self.home_bottom_cta_button_text
            if self.home_bottom_cta_button_text
            else None,
            "home_bottom_cta_body": self.home_bottom_cta_body
            if self.home_bottom_cta_body
            else None,
            "home_bottom_cta_button_page": self.home_bottom_cta_button_page
            if self.home_bottom_cta_button_page
            else None,
            "home_bottom_cta_button_url": self.home_bottom_cta_button_url
            if self.home_bottom_cta_button_url
            else None,
            "impact_featured_article": self.impact_featured_article
            if self.impact_featured_article
            else None,
            "impact_featured_article_heading": self.impact_featured_article_heading
            if self.impact_featured_article_heading
            else None,
            "impact_featured_article_title": self.impact_featured_article_title
            if self.impact_featured_article_title
            else None,
            "impact_featured_article_button_text": self.impact_featured_article_button_text
            if self.impact_featured_article_button_text
            else None,
            "impact_featured_article_excerpt": self.impact_featured_article_excerpt
            if self.impact_featured_article_excerpt
            else None,
            "show_fundraise_inspiration_section": self.show_fundraise_inspiration_section,
            "featured_event": self.featured_event if self.featured_event else None,
            "featured_news": self.featured_news if self.featured_news else None,
            "featured_story": self.featured_story if self.featured_story else None,
            "share_twitter_handle": self.share_twitter_handle
            if self.share_twitter_handle
            else global_settings.share_twitter_handle
            if global_settings.share_twitter_handle
            else None,
            "share_image": self.share_image
            if self.share_image
            else global_settings.share_image
            if global_settings.share_image
            else None,
            "share_description": self.share_description
            if self.share_description
            else global_settings.share_description
            if global_settings.share_description
            else None,
            "facebook_pixel": self.facebook_pixel,
        }

        return data
```

This is the code block in the wagtail 2.16 update that is causing my issues. It is trying to access a instance variable from the site root path but the get_site_root_paths() method is returning a list of site root paths causing the error

```
def _get_relevant_site_root_paths(self, cache_object=None):
        """
        .. versionadded::2.16
        Returns a tuple of root paths for all sites this page belongs to.
        """
        return tuple(
            srp
            for srp in self._get_site_root_paths(cache_object)
            if self.url_path.startswith(srp.root_path)
        )
```

Comment: This error is showing when you access the Django admin?! Is your Site model exposed in the django-admin?

Is this a single site? multiple sites in the same install? Are the site's nested or are all the site root pages siblings in the page tree? 

The only package pinning I see that I would question is wagtailmenus==3.1.2. While at Wagtail 2.16, you may want 3.1.1

Comment: There is a custom context processor that loads in site information

This site has multiple "offices" that are the different domains (similar but not exactly like subdomains) mostly used for localization but also used for office specific paages, forms, data etc.

The sites all share the same root pages etc they are as said above mostly used for localization but also for some office specific info like address and office specific forms posts articles etc

Comment: Because its a context processor it gets loaded wherever on the site which includes wagtail admin, django admin etc. This wasn't an issue at all in previous wagtail versions as I have it running just fine with wagtail 2.15.6 just when upgrading to 2.16 it breaks

Comment: Can you share the code to your context processor, and the serialized_data method it calls?

Comment: @gasman Updated with additional info see above

Comment: Please could you try running the following from the `./manage.py shell` command line, and let me know the output (feel free to redact any hostnames if necessary): `from wagtail.core.models import Site; Site.get_site_root_paths()`

Comment: [SiteRootPath(site_id=1, root_path='/home/', root_url='_____________', language_code='en')]

Comment: It is returning it as a list of site root paths which I think is the main issue but I am not sure how or why it is doing that as of the update

Comment: Although running that same code on the previous version returns the same listed site root paths. where the code that is causing me issues is not realizing it is getting a list returned and it is trying to directly access a variable from the site root path itself

Comment: @mjreffel Did you find a solution to this problem? Having the same one myself

Comment: For what it's worth for anyone that else that sees this in the future, I dealt with it by upgrading to 3.0 and the problem went away.